# Wanting to make date of birth automatically include dashes

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I am wanting to edit my rails app so that the user no longer has to type slashes when they are typing in the date of birth. The app already has it configured to where if you type in the social security number it automatically includes dashes. I figure it's the same logic, and should be an easy fix. I tried putting the following code in my app, but it is not updating at all. Is there something else I need to do? I edited in the line of code, but nothing is changing.

Here's what I have:

```
$(document).on('ajax:success','#new-member-button', function(event, response, status,xhr){
    $('.search-member-area').hide();
    $('#search-member').addClass('previous-stepp');
    $("#member-details").addClass('selected');
    $(response).appendTo($('.add-edit-member-area'));
    maskField('#member_social_security_number', '999-99-9999', '___-__-____');
    maskField('#member_phone_number', '999-999-9999', '(___) ___-____');
    maskField('#member_date_of_birth', '99/99/9999', '__/__/____'); //piece of code I added
});
```

I edited out the social_security_number to make sure that took it out, and it did. But when I add in the date of birth auto_formatter, it does nothing. Any ideas?

Edit: it appears date_of_birth is a DateTime and social_security_number is a varchar(50). Any ideas for how I would do this with a DateTime?

Edit 2: Here is my member model:

```
class Member < ActiveResource::Base

  self.site = ServiceConfig[:vbr_service_uri]
  self.element_name = 'member'
  self.include_format_in_path = false
  self.include_root_in_json = false
  self.format = :json

  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name, :date_of_birth, :social_security_number

  validates_format_of :zip_code, with: /\A\d{5}(-\d{4})?$\z/, message: 'should be in the form 12345 or 12345-1234', :allow_blank => true

  validates_format_of :phone_number, with: /\A(\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4})?\z/, message: 'should be in the form 555-555-5555', :allow_blank => true

  validates_format_of :social_security_number, with: /\A\d{3}-\d{2}-\d{4}$\z/, message: 'should be in the form 123-45-6789', :allow_blank => true

  def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
  end
end
```

Comment: you are not using dashes Oo
this maskField('#member_date_of_birth', '99-99-9999', '__/__/____')
should be this maskField('#member_date_of_birth', '99-99-9999', '__-__-____');

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes Oops. Good catch. But it is still not changing anything..

Comment: Is #member_date_of_birth a string?

Comment: Could you update the code? because when I posted the commentary, it wiped out the first underline

Comment: it should be this `maskField('#member_date_of_birth', '99-99-9999', '__-__-____');`

Comment: it's still not doing it. Although, I just figured out date_of_birth is a DateTime and social_security is a varchar(50). I guess now my question is, how would I do this with a DateTime?

Comment: it should not matter if the rendered html is an input. :o did you double check your *#member_date_of_birth* to see if it is really like that? the ID?

Comment: @HugoS.Mendes
Yeah, It is a part of Member class. Here I'll edit in some more info.

Comment: When you inspect element (the rendered html) how is the rendered html for this field?

Comment: It says "<input class="field-input" type="text" data-rule-datepicker="" autoclose="true" current="false" format="mm/dd/yyyy" keyboardnavigation="true" name="member[date_of_birth]" orientation="auto" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy" todayhighlight="true" value="" required="required" aria-required="true">"